# How to get specific DocuSign envelope ID out of completion mails

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to integrate DocuSign with a document management system to automate archiving processes. Due to company policies DocuSign is not sending out signed documents, instead the url to the DocuSign process is sent out. As of today, users have to manually open the link, download the documents and store them correctly in the enterprise DMS.

So far, so good - we checked the completion mails which DS sends out and it turns out, that DS is sending out different email with a different body from the PROD instance. The demo instance sends the url with the espei value (envelope id)

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?a=880bf5ba-014f-40e0-af10-2c27a0757823&r=2af56223-ae5e-4e64-af8c-8b8bdd5fb63e&espei=2382ea99-be29-4f3b-a0b2-b18416d941ae**https://demo.docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?a=880bf5ba-014f-40e0-af10-2c27a0757823&r=2af56223-ae5e-4e64-af8c-8b8bdd5fb63e&espei=2382ea99-be29-4f3b-a0b2-b18416d941ae**

PROD mails sent out contains also an URL, but without the envelope id
https://eu.docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?a=05d0fc40-de75-4eb8-825f-d3eaf10e4c21&r=f99cfae5-1e95-4e3a-833c-23e89f152263

Based on the envelope ID we are accessing the envelope and download the documents - well in the Demo instance.

So far I found no switch in the DS settings which would change that behavior - how the mail body url is prepared. Any idea where this switch could sit?

First I checked the accounts for any different settings, but if there is a switch, it is out of my admin control. Currently I try to reach out to DS for support - maybe there is a switch for that on their side.

And for a plan B without espei: I was sweeping the API documentation about how to get the envelope id out of the Emailstart.aspx "a" parameter, but failed. All of the API regarding the envelope id is about, that you get it once you created the envelope via api - but the envelope creation is still done via web portal, so that is not in my control. Which api part did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The *envelopeId* is not in the completion email or in the URL to DocuSign.
You could build an integration using [DocuSign connect](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/) that uses the *envelopeId* for your needs, but you'll have to write custom code to do this, can't just get it from regular completion emails.

Comment: So, we would have get list of envelopes which turned to "Completed" periodically and filter those out we already processed. That seems to be the only way to get an "envelope ID" except creating them on our own (which is planned 2024)...

Comment: no, you can use DocuSign Connect and get webhook for each envelope